# Integrate slack with bitbucket comments

Tags: bitbucket, slack

I have successfully installed bitbucket integration on slack. 
I get notifications on every commit, I want to also notified
when there is a new comment on bitbucket. Is that possible ?

Comment: The bitbucket integration used to notify me when a user commented on a PR (but not when comments were edited/deleted). Today, though, it suddenly stopped notifying me when a comment is created; now it only notifies when a comment is deleted.

Answer (score 2):

You can solve that by using webhooks. There is a script that's designed for pull requests but that will also post Bitbucket comments into a specified Slack channel:

https://github.com/lfilho/bitbucket-slack-pr-hook

You need to run that on your own server or deploy it to something like Heroku.
Also note that this still uses the old Bitbucket webhooks and therefore is not as mighty as it could be with the new hooks.

Slack had a support page where Bitbucket was listed as an "Upcoming enhancement", but the page is gone now. Below the original text of this answer.

> Slack itself lists Bitbucket as "Upcoming enhancements to existing integrations" in their support center: https://slack.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/202035138-Upcoming-Slack-integrations so maybe watch out for that.